# How to update the chosen-select text using Jquery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-chosen

I need to change the `chosen-select` text of one select option using Jquery. I am providing my code below.

```
<select name="countryCode" class="chosen-select" id="countryCode" required>
  <?php foreach ($countrydata as $key => $value) {
     if ($value['con_code']=='IN') {
          $select='selected';
      }else{
          $select='';
     }
 ?>
  <option data-text="<?php echo $value['country']; ?>" value="<?php echo $value['dial_code']; ?>" <?php echo $select; ?>><?php echo $value['country']; ?></option>
 <?php } ?>
</select>
```

The script part is given below.

```
$('.chosen-select').select2( { width:'100%', maximumSelectionSize: 1 } );
    $('#countryCode').html(
                       $('#countryCode').find(':selected').attr('value')
                     ).trigger('chosen:updated');
```

Here I need the selected value will be shown as its text.

Comment: where do you initialize chosen?

Comment: @madalinivascu : I updated my post.

Comment: is that select2 or chosen?

Comment: @madalinivascu: `select2`.

Comment: then why is your question about chosen?

Comment: why set maximum selection size at 1 when u are using select2?